# C# why can't I pass "base" interface by ref?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, ref

I want to know why this is a compile error, in order to understand the C# language better.

In my code I have an interface (IMyInterface) that derives from IDisposable. I have another method that takes a param of type 'ref IDisposable'. But I cannot pass a member var of type IMyInterface to that method. Here is my example code below:

```
using System;

namespace CompileErrorBaseInterface
{
    public interface IMyInterface : IDisposable { }

    class Program
    {
        private IMyInterface _myInterfaceObj;

        static void Main(string[] args) { }

        public void ExampleMethod()
        {
            MyMethodBaseInterface(ref _myInterfaceObj); //compile error
            MyMethodDerivedInterface(ref _myInterfaceObj); //no compile error
        }

        private void MyMethodBaseInterface(ref IDisposable foo) { }

        private void MyMethodDerivedInterface(ref IMyInterface foo) { }
    }
}
```

The compile errors are:

- Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref
  CompileErrorBaseInterface.IMyInterface' to 'ref System.IDisposable'
  The best overloaded method match for
- 'CompileErrorBaseInterface.Program.MyMethodBaseInterface(ref
  System.IDisposable)' has some invalid arguments

Can anyone explain why this is not allowed, or not possible for the compiler to do? I have a workaround using generics, so I just want to understand why it is not allowed to do it this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following example:

```
private void MyMethod(ref IDisposable foo)
{
    // This is a valid statement, since SqlConnection implements IDisposable
    foo = new SqlConnection();
}
```

If you were allowed to pass an `IMyInterface` to `MyMethod`, you'd have a problem, since you just assigned an object of type `SqlConnection` (which does not implement `IMyInterface`)  to a variable of type `IMyInterface`.

For more details, have a look at the following blog entry of C# guru Eric Lippert:

- [Why do ref and out parameters not allow type variation?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation/)